# awk with wildcard search not working

Tags: shell-script, awk

```
zcat * | awk -F"|" '$6==*404* {print  $0;}'
```

This command is not working. I have field separator pipe and where after the 6th pipe i have value `*404*` wildcard with 404 key value and want to print the entire line.

Comment: Don't you get an error? What is it? ([edit] the question). You said "`*404*` wildcard", but `==` performs literal matching. So should it be a wildcard in `awk`? Or did you call it wildcard because it looks like a globbing pattern?

Answer (score 0):

`zcat * | awk -F\| '$6 ~ "404"'`

If the sixth field matches "404" (regular expression test, so anywhere in its value), do the default (print the line).